# make my own work flow or use microsoft work flow 4?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Our company has a new big project all about work flows. (like user registers a request then operator1 should check then send the request to operator2 and after that send a continue message to user and then users completes his own first request and then it continues 20 levels until it is finished.)

because these types of work flows are a lot in the project and all of them may change many times later so I have to use work flow technology to handle this complication easier.

2 ways I know I can make this work flow:

way 1) I can use Microsoft Workflow 4 technology and and add a workflow project to my solution and make the work flow there and its versioning and other stuff.

way 2) I can make my own Workflow thing. make a graphical user interface for it and store activities in db and then make the versioning thing and then my project works with my workflow.

And now my question is this:

making my own workflow sounds easier for me (although I have to make every thing from scratch my self, the GUI and the behind coding, versioning and other stuff) because I can control it easier.
but using Microsoft wf4 I don't know. I have red all about it for 2 weeks now but I haven't understand it quite well. I know how to make a costume Activity and Bookmarks and stuff with it but I think using it will be a burden because  I think at the end I have to make every thing my self and store Bookmarks and user progress level in db my self.

Tell me this guys: Is it good to make my own workflow system? Can I make everything that Microsoft wf4 does? Suggest any thing. I just need Advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

WF4 is a bit tricky to learn.
I've used it and taught it for years and I find the best thing is to use it as a router to external classes.
Then you can take advantage of its strengths which are; persistence over long periods, versioning (easy if you load the xaml external files/database) and the design GUI.

Why reinvent something that already works.

Comment: when we have to save every thing in DB ourselves (like storing current bookmark and other stuff too) what is the reason of using wf4? just the GUI? versioning is very simple if we want to make it ourselves. for a long running task, when we store data in DB with an 'State' field we can continue our level of progress (any time) with it. Can't we?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be storing bookmarks in a database?  A persisted workflow restarts from where it left off, no need for bookmarks.

Comment: so where does a Bookmark store? Imagine IIS restarts or server gets shut down. after that how wf4 knows where it should continue a workflow from?

Comment: You use Persist for this scenario, not Bookmarks.
When you Persist, the location of the current execution point is stored.
Later on, after there has been an IIS restart or power failure, when you re-load the workflow then the workflow will commence execution at the point where it was persisted.
I put persistence points before and after activities that perform data change operations so that Persist is a pseudo transaction operation.
This stops a data change occurring twice.
Persist is to allow you save the whole workflow state
Bookmarks are to allow you to return to code in an activity

Comment: where do u save your Persists? in DB?

Comment: where do u save your Persists? in DB?

Comment: I use a MS Sequel database but you can use other storage if you want.
I use Sequel because the structure and logic is supplied by MS for wff.
As shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773(v=vs.110).aspx

Once the database is created then all workflows are linked to the persistence store and Persist then runs when required.  Either by calling Persist or by allowing the workflow to idle (I use a delay to trigger persist.  This allows code to be put inside the PersistableIdle call back for different scenarios.